# Simplify 2 similar json helper functions

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0, scalaz

I have two functions that are similar. One returns a String when successful and the second returns an Option[String] when successful. How can write this in a more elegant way, perhaps calling the first function in the second function? Thanks!

```
  private def readString(j: JsValue, key: String): Validation[String, String] = {
    j \ key match {
      case j: JsString =>
        Success(j.value)
      case j: JsUndefined =>
        Failure(s"Missing field $key")
      case j: JsValue =>
        Failure(s"Field $key value is not a string")
    }
  }

  private def readStringOpt(j: JsValue, key: String): Validation[String, Option[String]] = {
    (j \ key).as[JsValue] match {
      case j: JsString =>
        j.value.some.success
      case j: JsUndefined =>
        None.success
      case x =>
        Failure(s"Field $key value is not a string")
    }
  }
```

Comment: idk about validation but cant you simply map Validation[String, Option[String]] to Validation[String, String] ?

Comment: I suppose calling the second function in first works. I hadn't thought of that since I wrote the first function first. However, using the second function to create an option and then unwrapping it and adding bunch of other stuff is far more costly than the first function. Here is what the mapping looks like:                   readStringOpt(j, key).flatMap {
      case Some(s) => s.success
      case None => s"Missing field $key".failure
}. This seems to be an elegant soln, unless there's a more optimal and elegant soln.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the `.as[JsValue]` in your second method isn't really necessary—all it does is look up the `Reads` instance for `JsValue`, which just passes through its argument and never fails.

If you want to go the route you suggest above (defining the `Opt`-less version in terms of the other), Scalaz provides some slightly more concise syntax:

```
def readString(j: JsValue, key: String): Validation[String, String] =
  readStringOpt(j, key).flatMap(_.toSuccess(s"Missing field $key"))
```

This will give you a deprecation warning in recent versions of Scalaz, however, since `Validation` does not have a monad instance and its `flatMap` is kind of a lie. This means you have two options (apart from ignoring the deprecation warning): you can switch to `\/`, which is monadic, or you can use a fold instead:

```
def readString(j: JsValue, key: String): Validation[String, String] =
  readStringOpt(j, key).fold(_.failure, _.toSuccess(s"Missing field $key"))
```

Which is a little more verbose, but it puts you on the right side of the validation-is-not-a-monad gods.